# How can I check for overlapping enrollments based on userIDs in python-pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have 3 separate CSVs
Exit - has exit date and userIDs, and ProjectIDS
Entry - has entry date and userIDs, and ProjectIDS
Project - has valid projectsIDs, and projectTypes [Valid types are 0, 1, and 2)

I want to find which users have overlapping enrollments in valid projects, IE two entry dates before an exit date.

I was attempting to go about this by creating a dataframe of valid project ID's with isin(),
Then creating an events array for each userID with dimensions of DATE and Type, sorting it, check all ODD entries are Enrolls all EVEN entries are exits.

Any users who don't match this have simultaneous enrollments.

Here's my code:

```
exit = pd.read_csv('exit.csv')
enroll = pd.read_csv('enroll.csv')
project = pd.read_csv('project.csv')

df = pd.DataFrame(project)
ProjectTypes = [0, 1, 2]
project_valid = df[(df['ProjectType'].isin(ProjectTypes))]

df = pd.DataFrame(enroll)

enrollvalid = (df['ProjectID'].isin(project_valid['ProjectID']))
print("Enroll valids /n")

df = df[enrollvalid]



#So now I have my list of valid projectIDs,I can print valid userIDs like
print(df['userID'])
```

I was tempted to do something like user iterrows() to iterate over the rows in enroll and exit for each userID to get a list of enrollment and exit dates per user.

but afaik this should be do-able as vectors, I shouldn't have to iterate.

How can I get a list of enrollments/exits per user with pandas dataframes?
Specifically what would the alternative to iterrows() be?

Alternatively, if I should just go about solving this problem differently to find overlapping enrollments in valid projects, I'm open to more general ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I had a go, and eventually used `iterrows()`.

Mock data based on what I understood from your description:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Data + code:

```
import pandas as pd

entry = pd.DataFrame(
    columns=['entry_date', 'user_id', 'project_id'],
    data=[['2021-01-01', 'u1', 'p1'],
          ['2021-02-01', 'u1', 'p2'],
          ['2021-01-01', 'u2', 'p5'],
          ['2021-02-01', 'u2', 'p4'],
          ['2021-02-01', 'u3', 'p6'],
          ['2021-01-10', 'u3', 'p1'],
          ['2021-02-01', 'u4', 'p1'],
          ['2021-01-01', 'u5', 'p4'],
          ['2021-02-01', 'u5', 'p6'],
          ['2021-01-01', 'u5', 'p5']]
)

exit = pd.DataFrame(
    columns=['exit_date', 'user_id', 'project_id'],
    data=[['2021-01-11', 'u1', 'p1'],
          ['2021-02-03', 'u1', 'p2'],
          ['2021-01-07', 'u2', 'p5'],
          ['2021-02-14', 'u2', 'p4'],
          ['2021-02-06', 'u3', 'p6'],
          ['2021-02-07', 'u3', 'p1'],
          ['2021-02-09', 'u4', 'p1'],
          ['2021-01-13', 'u5', 'p4'],
          ['2021-02-13', 'u5', 'p6'],
          ['2021-01-15', 'u5', 'p5']]
)

project = pd.DataFrame(
    columns=['project_id', 'project_type'],
    data=[['p1', 0],
          ['p2', 1],
          ['p4', 2],
          ['p5', 0],
          ['p6', 1]
          ]
)
display(project, entry, exit)

#Convert to datetime
entry['entry_date'] = pd.to_datetime(entry.entry_date)
exit['exit_date'] = pd.to_datetime(exit.exit_date)

#Valid project ids
valid_types = [0, 1, 2]
valid_pids = project.loc[project.project_type.isin(valid_types), 'project_id'].unique()

#Find overlapping
overlap = pd.merge(entry, exit, how='outer', on=['user_id', 'project_id'], suffixes=('_entry', '_exit'))
overlap.sort_values('project_id').set_index(['project_id', 'user_id'])
overlap['overlaps_with'] = [list()] * len(df)

#Drop invalid project ids
overlap = overlap.loc[overlap.project_id.isin(valid_pids)]

for pid in overlap.project_id.unique():
    pid_df = overlap.loc[overlap.project_id==pid].sort_index()
    for idx, row in pid_df.iterrows():
        for oth_idx, oth_row in pid_df.iterrows():
            if oth_idx == idx:
                continue
            #Could use pd.Interval() here?
            #If dates overlap, record it
            if (oth_row.entry_date < row.entry_date and oth_row.exit_date < row.entry_date) or\
                (oth_row.exit_date > row.exit_date and oth_row.entry_date > row.exit_date):
                continue
            overlap.at[idx, 'overlaps_with'] = overlap.loc[idx].overlaps_with + [oth_row.user_id]
            # print(row.user_id, 'and', oth_row.user_id, 'overlap', 'idxs', idx, oth_idx)
            # display(overlap)

#View final result
overlap.set_index(['project_id', 'user_id']).sort_index()
```